# Open and Browse File when clicking on a button using Angular

Tags: angular

I want to display the UserManual on clicking on the help button, and I need to be able to browse on that manual and while opening the manual, always the home page should be as default, and it should be implemented in different languages as well

I am trying to open the user manual, but when I try to do, it is redirecting me to the home page

Comment: Be more specific.

Comment: Share the code, so that we can help.